# How to change background-image with React when a page is loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to change the background of the page when it loads without having to click the button?

```
import img1 from '../images/img1.jpg';
import img2 from '../images/img2.jpg';
import img3 from '../images/img3.jpg';

const [background, setBackground] = useState(img1);

const list = [img1, img2, img3];

const css = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${background})`,
};

return (
    <div style={css}>
        <button onLoad={() => setBackground(list)}>Change background</button>
    </div>
);
```

but `setBackground(list)}` does not read the array and the `onLoad` event does not work when the page is reloaded.

thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to change it immediately from `img1` to `img2`?

Comment: @Andy no, i'm trying change the image an each reload on page but doesn't happen

Comment: Instead of onLoad, you had to use useEffect for getting the component load. In react it's more of component load than page load.

Comment: You probably want to use a hook like [`useLocalStorage`](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) to persist the current image index which you can then check on the next reload and then move to the next one.

Comment: `setBackground` is supposed to be an image object, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above the solution requires *localStorage*, *useEffect*, *useRef*. All logic is inside *useEffect*, because when the component is mounting all the magic happens here. [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sound-mci6f?file=/src/App.js:23-1312)

1. Initialize an absolute number with *useRef*
2. Trying to get value from *localStorage*, if is empty then we set
   default value. And the same place, we checking the array index.
3. Second time avoid the check and we increace gotted value andabsolute
   number.
4. Then sending result to *state* and *localStorage*

**App.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const img1 = "https://dummyimage.com/400x200/a648a6/e3e4e8.png";
  const img2 = "https://dummyimage.com/400x200/4e49a6/e3e4e8.png";
  const img3 = "https://dummyimage.com/400x200/077d32/e3e4e8.png";

  let [lsNum, setLsNum] = useState(0);
  // Absolute number '1'
  let count = useRef(1);

  const list = [img1, img2, img3];

  useEffect(() => {
    // Get value from localStorage, transform to number
    const lS = Number(localStorage.getItem("image"));
    // Check! If localStorage have number 2 / more
    // Set number 0
    if (lS >= 2) {
      localStorage.setItem("image", 0);
      return;
    }
    // Get absolute number and increase with number from localStorage
    count.current = count.current + lS;
    // Set result to state
    setLsNum(count.current);
    // Set the resulting number to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("image", count.current);
  }, []);

  const css = {
    height: "200px",
    width: "400px",
    display: "block",
    backgroundImage: `url(${list[lsNum]})`, // index change
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    border: "1px solid red"
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={css}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```